# What __name__ string does uwsgi use?

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

What is the value of `__name__` in this example when running under uwsgi?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from livereload import Server
    server = Server(app.wsgi_app)
    server.serve()
```

I just want to ensure this **doesn't** run when I push it to a production server using uwsgi under Nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

**uwsgi_file__`<filepath>`**

Where the filepath has underscores for the `/`s and possibly other substitutions.  So when the path to the script that is running is

```
  /opt/www/example.com/www/blog.py
```

the `__name__` will be

```
  uwsgi_file__opt_www_example_com_www_blog
```

I did have to hack around on prod, but I think I got away with it.

Answer (score 3):

`__name__` will be equal to name of module plus filename from which your application is imported by uwsgi. For example: `my_project.server`. So code inside block will not run.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/uwsgi/

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore, the updated one is: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/deploying/uwsgi/

But it seems the best solution is to check that the module `uwsgi` exists (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945449/unit-testing-flask-app-running-under-uwsgi)